# Selected rows to insert in a dataframe-pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can insert rows in a pandas dataframe? I have a large dataframe and I am trying to identify specific values to repeat rows and inserting in the dataframe. For example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4],[1, 6],[2,3],[1,5]], columns=["a", "b"])
   a  b
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  1  6
3  2  3
4  1  5
```

Column "a" represent the number of row repetitions to inset in the dataframe, So I would like to get the following

```
   a  b
0  1  2
1  1  4
2  1  4
3  1  4
4  1  6
5  1  3
6  1  3
7  1  5
```

I tried to use append but the results is not what I expected. Here is what I have so far. I'll appreciate any insight.

```
df2 = df1[df1.a > 1]               # To select rows with values more than 1
repeats = (df2.iloc[0]["a"] - 1)   # number of repetitions -1
r2 = pd.concat([df2]*repeats, ignore_index=True)
df_modified = df1.append(r2, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `reindex` with `repeat`

```
df1.reindex(df1.index.repeat(df1.a)).assign(a=1).reset_index(drop=True)
Out[1266]: 
   a  b
0  1  2
1  1  4
2  1  4
3  1  4
4  1  6
5  1  3
6  1  3
7  1  5
```

Comment: Thank you, for your help. But what If I have some empty or NaN values in column "a" ?. I guess I'll get an error: 'Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Raul you can add two more steps , like df1=df.loc[df.a=='',], df2=df.loc[df.a!='',], Then do df2 for df1 , and concat the result of df2 ,  and df1

Comment: Thanks, Wen, but still the same error, also, I tried to clean it first using: df2=df1.dropna(subset = ['a']) and then use your code but it is not working. I'll appreciate any insights

Comment: @Raul that may not a nan try df2=df1.loc[df1.a!=‘ ‘].astype(int)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a nested list comprehension:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': 1, 
    'b': [b for a, b in df1[['a', 'b']].values for _ in range(a)]})

>>> df2
   a  b
0  1  2
1  1  4
2  1  4
3  1  4
4  1  6
5  1  3
6  1  3
7  1  5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
import numpy as np

res = pd.DataFrame({'a': 1, 'b': np.repeat(df1['b'].values, df1['a'].values)})

print(res)

   a  b
0  1  2
1  1  4
2  1  4
3  1  4
4  1  6
5  1  3
6  1  3
7  1  5
```

Comment: You may wish to reset your index to match the OP's target result.

Comment: @Alexander, Good point. Or more efficiently (as per my update), just use NumPy all the way :)